# iphone bring up address book contact

Tags: iphone, addressbook, contacts

I am having some trouble accessing the iphone addressbook given a ABReferenceID.

The method is being called correctly (accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath), all the #import stuff is fine (as I can save the data no problem).

I have a contact with ReferenceID = 69273024, I simply want to bring 'him up.

I am trying to do this with the following technique, but line 2 is wrong. I can't work out how to correctly integrate the number into the problem. Any tips?

```
ABPersonViewController *pvc = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];
pvc.displayedPerson = 69273024;

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:pvc animated:YES];
```

Regards, norskben.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `displayedPerson` property should be set to an ABRecordRef. You can get the ABRecordRef from the ABRecordID using [ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007210-CH3-SW15). You can get the ABAddressBookRef using [ABAddressBookCreate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007099-CH200-SW7).

**UPDATE**
Here is example code, but I haven't tested it:

```
ABPersonViewController *pvc = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];
pvc.displayedPerson = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(ABAddressBookCreate(),69273024);

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:pvc animated:YES];
[pvc release];
```

Comment: I threw the suggested code together in an update to the answer. Let me know if you find any issues.

Comment: yeah it helps, its close to what i now have, except now I'm not 100% sure i'm sending it the right number in the first place. Because I keep getting an empty contact view.
How can I ensure I have a good number to test with, which works with the above code you sent?

Comment: i just did further tests, and it seems that pvc.displayedPerson is being set to 0/null, when I call it as an integer/string.The NSlog data i get is SQL[19460:207] Record ID - 69284016; [19460:207] pvc.displayedPerson - (null)
on code:  NSLog(@"Record ID - %d", recordId); NSLog(@"pvc.displayedPerson - %@", pvc.displayedPerson);

Comment: i posted my full problem onto: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138923/iphone-addressbook-getting-null-item-in-abaddressbookgetpersonwithrecordid